# IoT Hub device not receiving all i.e. missing some cloud to device (C2D) messages

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I wrote a sample .net 5.0 application to understand the IoT Hub specifically the Cloud to device messages. The program utilizes below two Nuget packages

- Microsoft.Azure.Devices version 1.35.0 and
- Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client version 1.38.0

The program starts by first registering a new device (a GUID) with IoT Hub. It then sends 50 messages to it by setting correlation id as MsgId 1..50

Each message sent has expiry time of 1 hour from UTC Now. The defaultTtlAsIso8601 on service side is also at PT1H i.e. 1 hour.

*All 50 messages are sent without any issue. I have verified that under Cloud To Device message count on azure portal -> IoT Hub -> Explorer -> IoT Devices* as well.

The program then opens the connection to device specific queue using the code below.

***The problem is that it only receive around 40 of the 50 sent messages, on the device/receiver side (code as well as sample output below).***

I have also tried a variation wherein instead of setting `SetReceiveMessageHandlerAsync` I used `s_deviceClient.OpenAsync()` and then `var receivedMessage = await s_deviceClient.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` It produces the same results i.e. first ~10 messages are missed on receiver side.

Every time I run the program (Sample output is also below) it would miss approx 10 messages. Can anyone suggest what else to look at?

**Sender**

```
        private static async Task SendCloudToDeviceMessages(Guid deviceId, int totalMessageCount)
        {
            var serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(iotHubConfiguration.GetConnectionString(PermissionType.serviceconnect));

            var counter = 1;
            var sDeviceId = deviceId.ToString();
            while (counter != -1)
            {
                var commandText = $"Message No. {counter}";
                var messagePayload = $"{{\"commandText\":\"{commandText}\"}}";
                var eventMessage = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messagePayload))
                {
                    ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8.ToString(),
                    ContentType = "application/json",
                    CorrelationId = $"MsgId {counter}",
                    ExpiryTimeUtc = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
                };

                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Sending {commandText}");
                    await serviceClient.SendAsync(sDeviceId, eventMessage);
                    if(counter == totalMessageCount)
                    {
                        counter = -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) // 51st message will cause a exception with error 403004 as c2d queue limit is 50
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    counter = -1;
                }
            }
        }


        public string GetConnectionString(PermissionType permission)
        {
            Guard.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace(IoTHubHostName, nameof(IoTHubHostName));

            var permissionString = Enum.GetName(typeof(PermissionType), permission);
            Guard.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace(permissionString, nameof(permissionString));

            if (SasPolicies == null || SasPolicies.Count == 0 || !SasPolicies.Any(p => p.Permissions.Equals(permissionString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Sas Policies not defined for permission {permission}");
            }

            var policy = SasPolicies.First(p => p.Permissions.Equals(permissionString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            return $"HostName={IoTHubHostName};SharedAccessKeyName={policy.KeyName};SharedAccessKey={policy.AccessKey}";
        }
```

**Receiver**

```
    public class CloudMessageReceiver
    {
        private DeviceClient s_deviceClient;
        private ConnectionStatus status;

        private AzureDevice device;
        private int receiverNumber;

        public CloudMessageReceiver(Guid deviceId, AzureDevice device, int receiverNumber)
        {
            var connectionstring = $"HostName={device.IoTHubHostName};DeviceId={deviceId};SharedAccessKey={device.PrimarySymmetricKey}";
            s_deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionstring, TransportType.Mqtt);
            s_deviceClient.SetConnectionStatusChangesHandler(ConnectionStatusChangesHandler);

            this.device = device;
            this.receiverNumber = receiverNumber;
        }

        public async Task ReceiveCommands(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            DisplayMessage($"Starting");
            await s_deviceClient.SetReceiveMessageHandlerAsync(ReceiveMessageAndCompleteAsync, device, ct);
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            }

            DisplayMessage($"exiting loop.");
            await s_deviceClient.CloseAsync();
        }

        private async Task ReceiveMessageAndCompleteAsync(Message receivedMessage, object userContext)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessMessage(receivedMessage);
                await s_deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                DisplayMessage($"ReceiveMessageAndCompleteAsync {e}");
            }
        }

        private void ProcessMessage(Message receivedMessage)
        {
            string messageData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes());
            DisplayMessage($"Received message - dCount {receivedMessage.DeliveryCount} - msgId/corId/lockT {receivedMessage.MessageId}/{receivedMessage.CorrelationId}/{receivedMessage.LockToken} - data {messageData}");
        }

        private void ConnectionStatusChangesHandler(ConnectionStatus status, ConnectionStatusChangeReason reason)
        {
            DisplayMessage($"connection status change {reason}");
            this.status = status;
        }

        private void DisplayMessage(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O")}; Receiver {receiverNumber}; {status}; {message}");
        }
    }
```

**Sample output of the program** - Note this time I missed messages with correlation id of 1..8

```
New Device Id - 541905f6-b873-486b-9503-ec91c85d980e
Sending Message No. 1
Sending Message No. 2
Sending Message No. 3
Sending Message No. 4
Sending Message No. 5
Sending Message No. 6
Sending Message No. 7
Sending Message No. 8
Sending Message No. 9
Sending Message No. 10
Sending Message No. 11
Sending Message No. 12
Sending Message No. 13
Sending Message No. 14
Sending Message No. 15
Sending Message No. 16
Sending Message No. 17
Sending Message No. 18
Sending Message No. 19
Sending Message No. 20
Sending Message No. 21
Sending Message No. 22
Sending Message No. 23
Sending Message No. 24
Sending Message No. 25
Sending Message No. 26
Sending Message No. 27
Sending Message No. 28
Sending Message No. 29
Sending Message No. 30
Sending Message No. 31
Sending Message No. 32
Sending Message No. 33
Sending Message No. 34
Sending Message No. 35
Sending Message No. 36
Sending Message No. 37
Sending Message No. 38
Sending Message No. 39
Sending Message No. 40
Sending Message No. 41
Sending Message No. 42
Sending Message No. 43
Sending Message No. 44
Sending Message No. 45
Sending Message No. 46
Sending Message No. 47
Sending Message No. 48
Sending Message No. 49
Sending Message No. 50
Press any key to receive

Press control-C to exit.
DateTime;Receiver;Status;Message
2021-10-18T23:52:31.1711895Z; Receiver 0; Disconnected; Starting
2021-10-18T23:52:31.8820154Z; Receiver 0; Disconnected; connection status change Connection_Ok
2021-10-18T23:52:31.9666838Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 9/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd10 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 9"}
2021-10-18T23:52:31.9740397Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 10/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd11 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 10"}
2021-10-18T23:52:31.9744397Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 11/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd12 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 11"}
2021-10-18T23:52:31.9749889Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 12/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd13 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 12"}
2021-10-18T23:52:31.9755836Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 13/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd14 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 13"}
2021-10-18T23:52:31.9842039Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 14/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd15 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 14"}
2021-10-18T23:52:31.9884916Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 15/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd16 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 15"}
2021-10-18T23:52:31.9888335Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 16/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd17 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 16"}
2021-10-18T23:52:31.9955141Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 17/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd18 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 17"}
2021-10-18T23:52:31.9958093Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 18/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd19 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 18"}
2021-10-18T23:52:31.9961687Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 19/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd20 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 19"}
2021-10-18T23:52:31.9984223Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 20/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd21 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 20"}
2021-10-18T23:52:31.9987580Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 21/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd22 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 21"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.0046054Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 22/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd23 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 22"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.0070534Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 23/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd24 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 23"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.0092722Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 24/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd25 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 24"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.0155681Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 25/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd26 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 25"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.0158509Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 26/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd27 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 26"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.0212764Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 27/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd28 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 27"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.0215682Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 28/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd29 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 28"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.0404806Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 29/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd30 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 29"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.0413058Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 30/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd31 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 30"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.0602976Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 31/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd32 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 31"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.0780547Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 32/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd33 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 32"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.0800057Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 33/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd34 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 33"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.0928815Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 34/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd35 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 34"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.0978834Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 35/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd36 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 35"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.1105230Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 36/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd37 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 36"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.1126512Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 37/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd38 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 37"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.2376984Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 38/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd39 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 38"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.2395194Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 39/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd40 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 39"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.2655808Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 40/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd41 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 40"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.2822276Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 41/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd42 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 41"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.2829551Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 42/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd43 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 42"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.2964665Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 43/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd44 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 43"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.2970636Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 44/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd45 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 44"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.3134796Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 45/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd46 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 45"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.3141598Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 46/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd47 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 46"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.3443188Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 47/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd48 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 47"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.3448780Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 48/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd49 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 48"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.3591141Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 49/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd50 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 49"}
2021-10-18T23:52:32.3607982Z; Receiver 0; Connected; Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 50/82d1f9c1-fd4d-4c5f-8277-aa2e85c752dd51 - data {"commandText":"Message No. 50"}
```

**Program.cs**

```
    class Program
    {
        private static IoTHubConfiguration iotHubConfiguration;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // first we will create a new device and register it with iot hub
            // then we will mimic c2d msg flow and send a message(s). 
            // then start the receiver to get all the messages from device q mimicing essentially receiver down scenario and then coming up

            iotHubConfiguration = GetHubConfiguration();

            var deviceId = Guid.NewGuid();
            Console.WriteLine($"New Device Id - {deviceId}");

            var device = await RegisterDeviceWithIotHub(deviceId);

            await SendCloudToDeviceMessages(deviceId, 50);

            Console.WriteLine($"Press any key to receive");
            Console.ReadLine();

            await StartReceiver(deviceId, device);

            Console.WriteLine($"Finished.");
        }

        private static IoTHubConfiguration GetHubConfiguration()
        {
            var hc = new IoTHubConfiguration
            {
                IoTHubHostName = "***.azure-devices.net", // redacted
                SasPolicies = new List<SasPolicy>()
            };

            hc.SasPolicies.Add(new SasPolicy
            {
                KeyName = "iothubowner",
                AccessKey = "1hCa***=", // redacted
                Permissions = "owner"
            });

            hc.SasPolicies.Add(new SasPolicy
            {
                KeyName = "registryReadWrite",
                AccessKey = "LCf***95I=", // redacted
                Permissions = "registry"
            });

            hc.SasPolicies.Add(new SasPolicy
            {
                KeyName = "service",
                AccessKey = "yMA***Bk=", // redacted
                Permissions = "serviceconnect"
            });

            hc.SasPolicies.Add(new SasPolicy
            {
                KeyName = "device",
                AccessKey = "yM***Hc=", // redacted
                Permissions = "deviceconnect"
            });

            return hc;
        }

        private static async Task<AzureDevice> RegisterDeviceWithIotHub(Guid deviceId)
        {
            var registryManager = new IoTDeviceRegistryManager(iotHubConfiguration);
            return await registryManager.RegisterDevice(deviceId.ToString());
        }

        private static async Task SendCloudToDeviceMessages(Guid deviceId, int totalMessageCount)
        {
            var serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(iotHubConfiguration.GetConnectionString(PermissionType.serviceconnect));

            var counter = 1;
            var sDeviceId = deviceId.ToString();
            while (counter != -1)
            {
                var commandText = $"Message No. {counter}";
                var messagePayload = $"{{\"commandText\":\"{commandText}\"}}";
                var eventMessage = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messagePayload))
                {
                    ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8.ToString(),
                    ContentType = "application/json",
                    CorrelationId = $"MsgId {counter}",
                    ExpiryTimeUtc = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
                };

                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Sending {commandText}");
                    await serviceClient.SendAsync(sDeviceId, eventMessage);
                    if(counter == totalMessageCount)
                    {
                        counter = -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) // 51st message will cause a exception with error 403004 as c2d queue limit is 50
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    counter = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        
        private static async Task StartReceiver(Guid deviceId, AzureDevice device)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press control-C to exit.");
            using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                eventArgs.Cancel = true;
                cts.Cancel();
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
            };

            //try
            //{
            //    Parallel.For(0, 5, async i =>
            //    {
            //        await new CloudMessageReceiver(deviceId, device, i).ReceiveCommands(cts.Token);
            //    });
            //}
            //catch (Exception e)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(e);
            //}

            Console.WriteLine("DateTime;Receiver;Status;Message");
            var receivers = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                receivers.Add(new CloudMessageReceiver(deviceId, device, i).ReceiveCommands(cts.Token));
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(receivers);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally the mystery is solved. The below sequence works:

- Register a device with IoT Hub from service client
- Immediately following registration impersonate the device, connect to IoT Hub & close it.

  ```
        var client = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(iotHubConfiguration.GetConnectionString(PermissionType.deviceconnect), deviceId, Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.TransportType.Mqtt);
        await client.OpenAsync();
        await client.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
        await client.CloseAsync();
  ```
- Now send messages and receive all of them on device side.

It would seem, IoT Hub does preempt the messages that were sent to it before device connects to it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to follow-up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that your device app is actually receiving messages. There is the constructor which creates the device client, subscribes to the connection status callback, and that's it. There is a method called ReceiveCommands, but I don't see where that is called. Perhaps there is more program code where it is called?

We have a published sample for device C2D [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/tree/main/iot-hub/Samples/device/MessageReceiveSample). The service-side sample is [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/tree/main/iot-hub/Samples/service/ServiceClientSample).

I've copy your code to try it out and debug. Based on your output, I did not let the service and device code run at the same time. The service ran until the queue was full then quit, and then the device code ran. In my case, the device handled all of the C2D messages that were sent.

I don't know how you are coordinating the work between service and device client as that code wasn't shared. Unless those first 10 messages somehow expired (but the remaining 40 did not), or if there was a rogue device client reading those messages, I can't explain how your device client did not get the first 10.

Here is my interpreted Program.cs code:

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                eventArgs.Cancel = true;
                cts.Cancel();
                Console.WriteLine("Sample execution cancellation requested; will exit.");
            };

            await ServiceApp.SendCloudToDeviceMessagesAsync("drwDevice", 50);

            await new DeviceApp().ReceiveCommandsAsync(cts.Token);
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
    }
```

ServiceApp.cs code:

```cs
        internal static async Task SendCloudToDeviceMessagesAsync(string deviceId, int totalMessageCount)
        {
            using var serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString("REDACTED");

            for (int i = 0; i <= totalMessageCount; i++)
            {
                var commandText = $"Message No. {i}";
                var messagePayload = $"{{\"commandText\": \"{commandText}\"}}";
                var eventMessage = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messagePayload))
                {
                    ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8.ToString(),
                    ContentType = "application/json",
                    CorrelationId = $"MsgId {i}",
                    ExpiryTimeUtc = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                };

                try
                {
                    await serviceClient.SendAsync(deviceId, eventMessage);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Service app: sent {commandText}");
                }
                catch (Exception e) // 51st message will cause a exception with error 403004 as c2d queue limit is 50
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error sending message: {e}");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

DeviceApp.cs code:

```cs
internal class DeviceApp
    {
        private readonly DeviceClient _deviceClient;
        private ConnectionStatus _status;

        public DeviceApp()
        {
            var connectionstring = "REDACTED";
            _deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionstring, TransportType.Mqtt);
            _deviceClient.SetConnectionStatusChangesHandler(ConnectionStatusChangesHandler);
        }

        public async Task ReceiveCommandsAsync(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            DisplayMessage($"Starting device");
            await _deviceClient.SetReceiveMessageHandlerAsync(ReceiveMessageAndCompleteAsync, null, ct);
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), ct);
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException) { }
            }

            DisplayMessage($"Exiting device receive commands loop.");
            await _deviceClient.CloseAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            _deviceClient.Dispose();
        }

        private async Task ReceiveMessageAndCompleteAsync(Message receivedMessage, object userContext)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessMessage(receivedMessage);
                await _deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                DisplayMessage($"Device message processing failed due to: {e}");
            }
        }

        private void ProcessMessage(Message receivedMessage)
        {
            string messageData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes());
            DisplayMessage($"Device Received message - dCount {receivedMessage.DeliveryCount} - msgId/corId/lockT {receivedMessage.MessageId}/{receivedMessage.CorrelationId}/{receivedMessage.LockToken} - data {messageData}");
        }

        private void ConnectionStatusChangesHandler(ConnectionStatus status, ConnectionStatusChangeReason reason)
        {
            DisplayMessage($"Device connection status change {status}, reason {reason}");
            _status = status;
        }

        private void DisplayMessage(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow:O}; {_status}; {message}");
        }
    }
```

Here's my console output:

```
Service app: sent Message No. 0
Service app: sent Message No. 1
Service app: sent Message No. 2
Service app: sent Message No. 3
Service app: sent Message No. 4
Service app: sent Message No. 5
Service app: sent Message No. 6
Service app: sent Message No. 7
Service app: sent Message No. 8
Service app: sent Message No. 9
Service app: sent Message No. 10
Service app: sent Message No. 11
Service app: sent Message No. 12
Service app: sent Message No. 13
Service app: sent Message No. 14
Service app: sent Message No. 15
Service app: sent Message No. 16
Service app: sent Message No. 17
Service app: sent Message No. 18
Service app: sent Message No. 19
Service app: sent Message No. 20
Service app: sent Message No. 21
Service app: sent Message No. 22
Service app: sent Message No. 23
Service app: sent Message No. 24
Service app: sent Message No. 25
Service app: sent Message No. 26
Service app: sent Message No. 27
Service app: sent Message No. 28
Service app: sent Message No. 29
Service app: sent Message No. 30
Service app: sent Message No. 31
Service app: sent Message No. 32
Service app: sent Message No. 33
Service app: sent Message No. 34
Service app: sent Message No. 35
Service app: sent Message No. 36
Service app: sent Message No. 37
Service app: sent Message No. 38
Service app: sent Message No. 39
Service app: sent Message No. 40
Service app: sent Message No. 41
Service app: sent Message No. 42
Service app: sent Message No. 43
Service app: sent Message No. 44
Service app: sent Message No. 45
Service app: sent Message No. 46
Service app: sent Message No. 47
Service app: sent Message No. 48
Service app: sent Message No. 49
Error sending message: Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common.Exceptions.DeviceMaximumQueueDepthExceededException: C2D messages enqueued for the device exceeded the queue limit of 50,  see more at http://aka.ms/iothub403004
Tracking Id:6b9da06a56574592ad3d91d88c22569d-G:_Gateway_0_1-B:_Backend_0_6-P:bfd58de4-75a3-4fdf-ac8f-090874046f20-TimeStamp:10/19/2021 21:05:02
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.ServiceClient.SendAsync(String deviceId, Message message, Nullable`1 timeout)
   at StackOverflowC2d.ServiceApp.SendCloudToDeviceMessagesAsync(String deviceId, Int32 totalMessageCount) in C:\Users\drwill\source\repos\StackOverflowC2d\ServiceApp.cs:line 28
2021-10-19T21:05:02.7506273Z; Disconnected; Starting device
2021-10-19T21:05:04.0431030Z; Disconnected; Device connection status change Connected, reason Connection_Ok
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1010787Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 0/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c403 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 0"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1204517Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 1/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c404 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 1"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1262404Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 2/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c405 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 2"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1273889Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 3/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c406 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 3"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1282134Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 4/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c407 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 4"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1297133Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 5/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c408 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 5"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1314598Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 6/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c409 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 6"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1359492Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 7/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c410 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 7"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1390582Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 8/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c411 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 8"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1401246Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 9/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c412 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 9"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1428137Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 10/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c413 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 10"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1492348Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 11/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c414 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 11"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1581056Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 12/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c415 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 12"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1607134Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 13/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c416 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 13"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1620858Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 14/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c417 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 14"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1693187Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 15/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c418 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 15"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1717445Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 16/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c419 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 16"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1733929Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 17/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c420 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 17"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1742426Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 18/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c421 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 18"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1756639Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 19/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c422 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 19"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1775303Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 20/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c423 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 20"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1838058Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 21/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c424 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 21"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1883744Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 22/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c425 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 22"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1893534Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 23/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c426 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 23"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1904443Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 24/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c427 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 24"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1918347Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 25/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c428 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 25"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1937234Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 26/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c429 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 26"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1958245Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 27/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c430 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 27"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.1980012Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 28/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c431 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 28"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2056523Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 29/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c432 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 29"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2066763Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 30/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c433 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 30"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2087691Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 31/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c434 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 31"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2097434Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 32/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c435 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 32"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2152579Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 33/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c436 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 33"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2189955Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 34/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c437 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 34"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2199206Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 35/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c438 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 35"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2222182Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 36/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c439 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 36"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2237384Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 37/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c440 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 37"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2248854Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 38/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c441 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 38"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2259717Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 39/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c442 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 39"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2277903Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 40/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c443 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 40"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2354922Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 41/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c444 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 41"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2365608Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 42/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c445 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 42"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2375759Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 43/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c446 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 43"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2387395Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 44/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c447 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 44"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2399055Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 45/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c448 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 45"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2414694Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 46/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c449 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 46"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2465376Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 47/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c450 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 47"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2506629Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 48/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c451 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 48"}
2021-10-19T21:05:04.2514837Z; Connected; Device Received message - dCount 0 - msgId/corId/lockT /MsgId 49/0c404da3-7672-487c-b47d-8d817543455c452 - data {"commandText": "Message No. 49"}
2021-10-19T21:05:13.7354899Z; Connected; Exiting device receive commands loop.
2021-10-19T21:05:13.7409149Z; Connected; Device connection status change Disabled, reason Client_Close
Sample execution cancellation requested; will exit.
Done
```

[Edit] updated result

Comment: That's correct, its called by the from program.cs not shown above. Here it is for reference, it just a call to ReceiveCommands (added above in the question as comment section is not long enough)

Appreciate you taking the time to debug it.

Comment: Thanks David for your time. There does not seems to be any discernible difference in two programs except that you are not registering the device but instead took an already registered device. 

The only thing that comes to mind is that there may be some catchup that iot hub service has to do when a new device is registered. So I started putting some delays between registration, c2d message sender and receiver but that did not help either. I guess next step is to reach out to MS.